# Action of symmetry group on homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-actions, geometric-topology, simplex

For a singular n-simplex $\alpha$ and a permutation $t\in S_{n}$, define $t\alpha$ to be the simplex with vertices permuted by $t$. Do we have $t\alpha$ homologous to $\text{sgn}(t)\alpha$ ? And does this gives an action of $S_n$ on $H_n$?

I can see for $n=1$ this is true, since the reverse of vertices gives opposite path in fundamental group, and $H_1$ is the abelianization of it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem with this construction is that the vertex permutation operation does not necessarily map cycles to cycles. Therefore, it cannot possibly define a map on homology groups.

For example, let's choose $X = \mathbb R^3$ as our topological space, and let $p, q, r, s$ be any four distinct points in $X$. Let $\tau \in C_2(X)$ be the chain
$$\tau = [q, r, s] - [p, r, s] + [p, q, s] - [p, q, r],$$
where, for example, the singular $2$-simplex $[q, r, s]$ is defined to be the *affine* map from the standard $2$-simplex to the triangle with vertices $q, r, s$.

Applying the boundary map $\partial$ to $\tau$, we obtain
\begin{align} \partial (\tau) & = [r, s] - [q, s] + [q, r] - [r, s] + [p, s] - [p, r] + [q, s] - [p, s] + [p, q] - [q, r] + [p, r] - [p, q] \\ &= 0. \end{align}
This shows that $\tau$ is a *cycle*.

Now, take $t \in S_3$ to be the permutation $t = (1, 2, 3)$. Acting on $\tau$ with $t$ by vertex permutation, we obtain
$$ t \tau = [r, s, q] - [r, s, p] + [q, s, p] - [q, r, p].$$

And now, if we apply the boundary map $\partial$ to $t \tau$, we get
\begin{align} \partial (t \tau) & = [s, q] - [r, q] + [r, s] - [s, p] + [r, p] - [r, s] + [s, p] - [q, p] + [q, s] - [r, p] + [q, p] - [q, r] \\ & = [s, q] + [q, s] - [r, q] - [q, r],  \end{align}
which does not vanish. Thus $t \tau$ is *not a cycle*.

---

For completeness, I'll answer your original question too.

> If $\alpha$ is a singular $n$-simplex, then is $t\alpha$ homologous to $\alpha$?

In other words:

> If $\alpha$ is a singular $n$-simplex, then does there exist a singular $(n+1)$-chain $\rho$ such that $t\alpha - \alpha = \partial \rho$?

Suppose that the statement is true for all singular $n$-simplexes $\alpha$. Then the statement must be true for all singular $n$-chains as well.

Let's consider the example of the singular $2$-chain $\tau$ on $X = \mathbb R^3$, as defined above. Notice that
$$ \tau = \partial ([p, q, r, s]).$$

Suppose there exists a singular $3$-chain $\rho$ such that $$t\tau - \tau = \partial \rho.$$

Then it would follow that
$$ t\tau = \partial([p, q, r, s] + \rho).$$

Therefore,
$$ \partial(t\tau) =\partial \partial([p, q, r, s] + \rho) = 0,$$
since the boundary of a boundary is always zero.

This contradicts our earlier calculation, where we found that $\partial(t\tau)$ is non-zero.

Comment: In page 211 of Hatcher’s algebraic topology, he proved that the action of $t$ that reversing the order of vertices of simplex with a sign modification is homotopic to identity, does this mean that, in this special case, two problems have positive answer?

Comment: For the two problems you posed to have a positive answer, the action of of $t$ should be a **chain map**, i.e. $t\partial=\partial t$. If $t$ is a chain map, then $t$ maps cycles to cycles and boundaries to boundaries.  Hence $t$ defines s map on homology.

Comment: Being homotopic to the identity is something you try to prove after you have already shown that $t$ is a chain map. Being homotopic to the identity implies that the action of $t$  on homology is the identity homomorphism.